# SQL stored procedure only return first row of table created by function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a function which converts a delimited VARCHAR into a table of INTs.

IntSplit:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[IntSplit]    Script Date: 02/10/2016 15:17:06 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IntSplit]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Data' = CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos))
    FROM Split
)

GO
```

When I run this in a query:

```
SELECT * FROM IntSplit('1,2,3', ',')
```

I get the expected result of:

```
 |Data
-+----
1| 1
2| 2
3| 3
```

I also have a stored procedure that does exactly the same thing (i.e. calls the function)

my_int_split:

```
USE [master]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[my_int_split]    Script Date: 02/10/2016 15:29:16 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_int_split]
(@i_ids VARCHAR)
AS
    -- Common set conditions
    -- Explicity suppress count information
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    -- Unhandled exception aborts whole transaction
    SET XACT_ABORT ON
    -- Autocommit on
    SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
    -- UK datetime
    SET DATEFORMAT dmy
    --
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    --
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM IntSplit(@i_ids, ',')
    END

GO
```

However, if I run the stored procedure with

```
my_int_split '1,2,3'
```

then I only get the first row back as the result

```
 |Data
-+----
1| 1
```

As far as I can tell the stored procedure is doing EXACTLY THE SAME THING as the query, but only ever returns the top row. Note that if I put in a VARCHAR of '2,3,4' it will return a single row of value 2, so it's not just always spitting 1 back out.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you didn't declared the length of the parameter for your stored procedure, so it assumes it's a `varchar(1)`. **Always** declare the length that you need, could be `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_int_split] (@i_ids VARCHAR(2000))`

Comment: Check varchar Length

Comment: Man, I love you guys. @Lamak, you were absolutely spot on. I shan't be making that mistake again in a hurry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never ever use `VARCHAR` without a length, your `@i_ids` parameter is being truncated to 1 character.

If you know how long the list of IDs may become, use this as a guide to specify the max length (plus some slack); otherwise use `VARCHAR(MAX)` which is less efficient but pretty much arbitrary in size.

Also, avoid to mix `NVARCHAR` (in the function) and `VARCHAR` (in the SP) - doing so can cause performance degregation due to conversions. Also (while not applicable in this specific case) it can cause indexes to be skipped because the data type is not identical.

The "funny" thing is that the length assumed when no length is given is not consistent. See [Aaron Bertrand's blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) for more details on this.